# I need to know the explanation of this sentence in c++ " b = (c > 5) ? a/c/2 : 0; "

Tags: c++

I need to know the explanation of this sentence in C++
I am editing a library for BL0937 where it uses energy monitoring paramteres , I have just used a b c for simplicity

```
b = (c > 5) ? a/c/2 : 0;
```

Comment: no Arpan G, its as it is written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x ? y : z` is a ternary operator that means "if x, then y, otherwise z."

`a/c/2` is just a simple chain of division. As the division operator (`/`) evaluates from left to right, it is equivalent to `(a/c)/2`.

So your expression first evaluates `c>5` and if that is true, it will evaluate to `a/c/2`, and otherwise 0. The evaluated value (either `a/c/2` or 0) will be assigned to the variable `b`.

Comment: I was getting confused by the division

Answer (score 4):

That can be rewritten as

```
if(c>5)
{
    b = (a/c)/2;
}
else
{
    b = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll mention more rules of operator precedence for c++, in case that you might be confused of the precedence of `/` and `x ? y : z`.

Here is an official page for operator precedence: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

From this, you know operator `/` has much priority to `x ? y : z` and `=`, and thus it is firstly calculated **from left to right**, i.e. `a/c/2` equals `(a/c)/2`. And then `x ? y : z` has the same precedence as `=`, calculated **from right to left**. Now it means:

```
b = ( (c>5) ? ((a/c)/2) : 0 );
```

Hope it helps.